# Associating a driver with a new printer using the CUPS API

Tags: linux, macos, cups

I'm attempting to add a new printer with a specific driver via the CUPS Library.

By following the code for the cups admin module (https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/master/cgi-bin/admin.c), I have managed to get the printer added as a raw printer, but not sure how to associate it with a specific driver.

I have tried setting ppd-name and printer-make-and-model, but that usually just ends up failing or simply adding a raw printer.

Any advice/suggestions on attempting to associate the new printer with a specific driver via ippRequests.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Consider [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).